# Recursion conditions and base case confirmation

Tags: java, recursion

I found this piece of code which solves how to find a word in a given 2D matrix challenge. I'm trying to understand the author's approach.

https://gist.github.com/Ray1988/8479951

But there are a few questions i have on it. Hoping you can shed some light here.

**Question #1**
In line 22, i don't fully understand the second OR condition statement:

```
if (board[row][col]!=word.charAt(i)|| checker[row][col])
```

How do you read the second stated, if checker in x and y position is true?? if checker exists?? what's the point for that?

**Question #2**

line 28, seems to be the base case for recursion, which ones fulfilled it will stop the iterations. Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answer to Question #1: 
look at the Author's description: it includes "The same letter cell may not be used more than once"
Author used checker to keep track of used cells. So if the checker[row][col] is true that means it is already used.

Answer to Question #2:
You are partially right. Actually line 22 and line 28 are both base cases because they do not self call the function, but check for some condition(s) and stop if fulfilled

Comment: changed titles from "Question #.." to "Answer to Question #.." as @Partho63 suggested

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ajay, that solves my questions, appreciate it!!

Comment: Good. I am happy that my answer is helpful to you @Alonso hernandez. Actually I didn't fully study the code to answer the question. Can you press the tick and make the answer as accepted.